# Generate interactions variables for Lasso and Ridge Regression automatically

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, interaction

I want to run a lasso and ridge regression for a out of sample predictions of wages.

I have 13 explanatory variables and want generate all possible interactions terms and also maybe ^2 them order ^3 them and so on till maybe ^5. I also want to ^2 t and ^3 and so on the  explanatory variables on there own.

Is there a possible way to do this automatically?

With for example `model.matrix(y~(V1+V2+V3)^2, dataFrame)` I get interactions therms but they are not `^2` only `v1*V2 + V1*V3 + V2*V3`. I also want `(V1*V2)^2` maybe and so on.

Comment: Check the documentation of `formula`. From there: "For example `(a+b+c)^2` is identical to `(a+b+c)*(a+b+c)` which in turn expands to a formula containing the main effects for `a`, `b` and `c` together with their second-order interactions". Also, probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577420/how-to-generate-all-first-order-interaction-terms-for-lasso-logistic-regression).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate all first-order interaction terms for Lasso Logistic Regression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577420/how-to-generate-all-first-order-interaction-terms-for-lasso-logistic-regression)

Comment: i edit my questions

Comment: I think the answer to this thread meets your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580267/how-to-make-all-interactions-before-using-glmnet